# Error when comparing values in float array

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, structure

I had made a program which calculate and store data in form of array structure,and at the end of the code, I will find the car plate with slowest speed and greatest speed.BUT I encountered a weird output for the "find the slowest car section".

it shows somethings like this
Slowest speed = 0.000000
Car = 6954000

Fastest speed = 300.000000
Car = 13
Process returned 9 (0x9)   execution time : 24.881 s
Press any key to continue.

//it is weird cuz the "fastest" can work but the slowest just cant//

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Car
{
    int plate;
    float time,distance,speed;

};

int main ()
{
    int n;
    struct Car car[10];
    int fcar,scar;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){

        printf ("\nPlate = ");
        scanf("%d",&car[n].plate);

        printf ("Distance = ");
        scanf("%f",&car[n].distance);

        printf ("Time = ");
        scanf("%f",&car[n].time);

        (car[n].speed) = (car[n].distance)/(car[n].time);
        printf ("Speed = %f",car[n].speed);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
        if (car[n].speed< 70){
            printf("\nSlow\n");

        }else if (car[n].speed>=70 && car[n].speed<110){
            printf("\nNormal\n");

        }else{
            printf("\nFast\n");

        }

        printf("-----------------------------------------------------");
    }


    float minn = car[0].speed;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        if ( car[n].speed < minn){
            minn = car[n].speed;
            scar = car[n].plate;
        }
    }
   printf("\n\nSlowest speed = %f",minn);
    printf("\nCar = %d",scar);

    float maxx = car[0].speed;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        if ( car[n].speed > maxx){
            maxx = car[n].speed;
            fcar = car[n].plate;
        }
    }
   printf("\n\nFastest speed = %f",maxx);
    printf("\nCar = %d",fcar);




    }

//-------------------------------
```

Comment: `for (n=1;n<=10;n++){` should start at 0

Comment: you are doing everything in loop, instead read the entries first and then write the algorithm to find the slow and fast speed

Comment: Use `for (n=1;n<10;n++){`  (`<=` --> `<`)

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (car[n].speed< 70){` and `}else if (car[n].speed>=70 && car[n].speed<110){`   The variable `speed` is a `float`, and these statements are comparing a `float` value to a `int` value.  Suggest: `if (car[n].speed< 70.0f){` and `}else if (car[n].speed>=70.0f && car[n].speed<110.0f){`  which declares the literals as having type `float`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"it is weird cuz the "fastest" can work but the slowest just cant"*.

Your code is likely invoking  [undefined behavior](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).  Read on...

The array:

```
   struct Car car[10];
```

Defines an array having 10 elements, and because C arrays are zero based), they are indexed  from  0  -  9.  Not 1 - 10.  So the  statement :

```
for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
```

Reaches *index out of bounds* at 'n == 10', where it will attempt to write to memory not own by your process.  Note that although this will compile without warning,  and may even *appear* to work for awhile, it will always be a  potential for  invoking   [undefined behavior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) at run-time, causing your program to crash for what may appear to be no reason.

Change to:

```
for (n=0;n<10;n++){
```

***Note***: This same error occurs in two places.  Apply the same edit to both.

Aside: regarding the following  initialization:

```
     float minn = car[0].speed;
```

I suggest using an explicitly large value such that it guarantees a trigger during the first test for minimum, eg:

```
  float minn = 200.0f;
```

because this value  is outside the bounds of any possible value that will be measured for  minn, and  thus forcing the first test to make a new new
Similar for the maxx initialization.   Eg;

```
 float maxx = -1.0f;
```

Comment: but i have 10 data to store ,shud i change to <11?

Comment: when we `array[10] ` the start element stores at 0 and last element stores at 9, so 0 to 9 gives 10 elements, as for loops you can use `for(int i =0; i<10; i++) `  in this case

Comment: @siah yih Hoong student -    Indexing in C is zero based.  So in your example 10 value can be  stored array elements with indices  0 to 9

Comment: OT: regarding: `float maxx = -1.0;` and `float minn = 200.0;`  the `-1.0` and `200.0` are `double` literals.  Should be: `-1.0f` and `200.0f`

Comment: @user3629249 - Good call. Edited.  Thanks .